# Nonetype on API call

Tags: python, python-3.x, qualtrics, http.client

using http.client to export survey responses from Qualtrics.  In order to get my survey responses I required the progress Id...  when I create the data export I am able to see the result of it but get NoneType error when trying to get the value I need:

```
import http.client

baseUrl = "https://{0}.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/{1}/export-responses/".format(dataCenter, surveyId)
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-api-token": apiToken
}
downloadRequestPayload = '{"format":"' + fileFormat + '","useLabels":true}'

downloadRequestResponse = conn.request("POST", baseUrl, downloadRequestPayload, headers)
downloadRequestResponse

{"result":{"progressId":"ES_XXXXXzFLEPYYYYY","percentComplete":0.0,"status":"inProgress"},"meta":{"requestId":"13958595-XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-407d23462XXX","httpStatus":"200 - OK"}}
```

So I clearly see the progressId value I need but when I try to grab it...

```
progressId = downloadRequestResponse.json()["result"]["progressId"]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'
```

(I know I can use the requests library Qualtrics suggests but for my purpose I need to use http.client or urllib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection

`conn.request` doesn't return anything (which in Python, means it returns `None`, and this is why your error is happening).

To get the response, use `getresponse`, which when called after a request is sent, returns an HTTPResponse instance.

Also, note that there is no `json` method in an HTTPResponse object. There is a `read` method, though. You may need to use the `json` module to parse the contents.

```
...
import json
conn.request("POST", baseUrl, downloadRequestPayload, headers)
downloadRequestResponse = conn.getresponse()
content = downloadRequestResponse.read()
result = json.loads(content)
```

Comment: thanks I totally just missed the json.loads(data)... got it now